# Remove .html from URL and rewrite requests to index.html

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm not very experienced with `.htaccess` related stuff, I was looking to get some help. Basically what I'm trying to do is this:

Any request that looks like this (example):

```
/foo.html
```

Would be rewrote to:

```
/foo
```

And any request that is a static file, I'd like it serve:

```
/index.html
```

Does that make sense? Any idea how to do this?

### Example

Here's what I have so far, though it's not correct as far as I know:

```
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: I didn't get your 2nd requirement. What do you mean by **any request that it's a static file**

Comment: @anubhava sorry, I mean *is*.

Comment: Your comment got truncated. Better you edit question to clarify with examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for existence of `.html` file before adding it to URIs:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]

RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Comment: Hmm, I got a 500 Internal Server Error using this.

Comment: It happens with any URL I try.

Comment: I found a typo mistake in my code. Fixed it now, retry now.